# Разрешение монитора

Tags: x11, xfce, debian, linux

Не могу настроить разрешение. Сейчас 1024х768, а для комфорта нужно 1280х1024.

Linux pc 3.2.0-2-686-pae # 1 SMP Sun Apr 15 17:56:31 UTC 2012 i686 GNU / Linux

ОС: Distributor ID: Debian         Description: Debian GNU / Linux testing (wheezy)         Release: testing         Codename: wheezyМенеджер окон: Xfce 4.8

Монитор PHILIPS 170S.Материнская плата: Asus P5QL-CMВидео интегрированное: GMA X4500

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего такие проблемы при отсутствии видеодрайвера. В таком случае система ставит стандартный, весьма ограниченный по функциональности. Надо смотреть на сайте производителя, например http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx?lang=rus, возможно и удастся проблему решить. У меня почти на всём оборудовании такие проблемы были, и все решались именно так. Очень важно подбирать под конкретный дистрибутив и сборку ядра, это достаточно критично.

Comment: На самом деле, все оказалось на много проще. Монитор был подключен через КВМ свитч. После того как кабель подключил на прямую к компьютеру, все стало на свои места без моего вмешательства!